Activating virtualenv does not change python interpreter path
I am trying to use a vritualenv in my project, but after activating it with:
source venv/bin/activate

The python interpreter seems to be still the python installed directly in the machine:
(venv) antonio@antonio-Modern-14-A10RB:~/TFG$ which python
/usr/bin/python



How did you create the virtualenv? Have you tried recreating it? Have you tried which python3 too?

Recreating it solved the problem, thanks and sorry for asking such a basic question.

No worries, glad you got it solved! :)
